# Execute command in terminal on startup on Pi

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have a simple card reader program on a Pi that reads input from a USB Card Reader (acts like a keyboard) and writes it to a text file. Hence, for this program to work, the program needs to be run on the terminal so the raw input from the card reader will be detected. I want this program to run every time my pi turns on so I need a way to open the terminal and execute the code inside the terminal on startup. Can anyone help me out?

```
import datetime
import time

card = raw_input()
t = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    f = open("Laptop Sign Out" + '.txt', 'a')
    f.write("Card Number: " + card[1:10] + " Time: " + t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(';')
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)

gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: Can't you add the command for the program to ~/.bashrc ?

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to make a sh/bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
(sudo) python <file_address>
```

From there, this should help:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: I need the terminal window to be open on startup and the program executed in it so the card reader input will be read. Am I doing something wrong with the method or do you know another way?